# How to stop all services

Tags: services

I'm looking for a command to stop all services running and probably restart them after.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Uhm... reboot? Since you want to stop literally every service.

Comment: May i ask what you want to achieve? Or why you need to stop ALL services?

Comment: For which Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 4):

assuming you are using ubuntu 16.04 you can use systemctl to control services.

to get a list of services and their status

```
systemctl | grep service
```

to control an individual service , replace service with the service name

```
systemctl status service
systemctl stop service
systemctl start service
```

in older version of ubuntu services can be controlled via init scripts which live in /etc/init.d , these work in a similar way

to get a list of services

```
ls -l /etc/init.d/
```

to contrl and individual service

```
/etc/init.d/service status
/etc/init.d/service stop
/etc/init.d/service start
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I highly recommend **rebooting** the machine instead, you can write a command to achieve this:

**Note**: This may force a machine reboot halfway through at which point this effort is profitless.

```
for s in `systemctl | grep service | cut -d '.' -f 1`; do sudo systemctl restart $s; done
```

I would instead list all currently running services, identify the ones I want to stop, then manually restart each service:

**Note**: *restart* internally calls *start + stop* so you won't have to perform them separately.

1. List currently running services:

   `systemctl | grep running`
2. Restart each service by typing:

   `systemctl restart <service>`